# Jekyll & Wercker - How to deploy a subdirectory

Tags: ftp, continuous-integration, jekyll, continuous-deployment, wercker

**Problem:** I am having difficulty deploying the Jekyll build folder to an FTP server via Wercker.

I've been using [Wercker](http://wercker.com) for continuos integration of a Jekyll site I'm working on. Using the script below, The build process: `jekyll build` and `jekyll doctor` appear to be working as intended.

My deploy step should upload the "_site" folder to my FTP server. I'm currently using duleorlovic's ftp-deploy wercker step. It's currently uploading the entire directory, instead of just the build folder.

**However**, Jekyll uses the `/_site` folder as the directory for where the site gets built to ... how could I limit my upload to just the `/_site` build folder?

*Thanks.*

Current `wercker.yml` as follows:

```
# Wercker Configuration
# continuous delivery platform that helps software developers 
# build and deploy their applications and microservices

box: ruby
build:
  steps:

    # Install dependencies
    - bundle-install

    # Execute jeykyll doctor command to validate the
    # site against a list of known issues.
    - script:
        name: jekyll doctor
        code: bundle exec jekyll doctor

    - script:
        name: jekyll build
        code: bundle exec jekyll build --trace

deploy:
  steps:
    - duleorlovic/ftp-deploy:
        destination: $FTP_SERVER
        username: $FTP_USERNAME
        password: $FTP_PASSWORD
        timeout: 15
        remote-file: remote.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the question.

Apparently Worker offers an environment variable called `$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR`. This directory is the folder that gets piped to the deploy step when the build step passes. If not passed anything, the deploy step just used the root directory (aka *not* your build folder).

The working `wercker.yml` contains the `jekyll build` step as follows:

```
   - script:
       name: jekyll build
       code: bundle exec jekyll build --trace --destination "$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR"
```

I wasn't able to find much for Wercker docs on the matter, since it seems like thier in transition between versions, but I found the solution in an example of how to use wercker.

You can see the example of using the Output Directory in their guide [How Wercker Works.](http://blog.wercker.com/2013/07/12/How-wercker-works.html)

Answer (score 0):

By passing the `cwd:` argument to the step you can change the working directory (according to the [wercker doc](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/steps)):

```
deploy:
  steps:
  - duleorlovic/ftp-deploy:
      cwd: _site/
      destination: $FTP_SERVER
      username: $FTP_USERNAME
      password: $FTP_PASSWORD
      timeout: 15
      remote-file: remote.txt
```